# How to convert audio to an appropriate input of seamless model?

Tags: audio, feature-extraction, huggingface

Facebook has released [a language model on huggingface](https://huggingface.co/facebook/seamless-m4t-large), which is useful to covert speech to text and etc.

Following the example in [here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/seamless-m4t-large), I can transcribe audio to text but not all audios. It seems that the output text highly depend on features of the input audio. I like to know what features of audio I should change to have an appropriate input.

I tried the following code to make sure that the sample-rate is 44100, and also the audio contains mono channel. But it seems the following changes are not enough, and there are something else I need to change in the audio input to have good output text.

```
import torchaudio
import torch

def stereo_to_mono_convertor(signal):
    if signal.shape[0] > 1:
        mono_signal = torch.tensor([signal[0].tolist()])
    else:
        mono_signal = signal
    return mono_signal

audio_path = "myAudio.wav"
waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(audio_path)
waveform = stereo_to_mono_convertor(waveform)
resampler = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(orig_freq=sample_rate, new_freq=44100)
waveform = resampler(waveform)

bit_depth = 4
quantization = torchaudio.transforms.MuLawEncoding(quantization_channels=2**bit_depth)
waveform = quantization(waveform)
waveform = waveform.to(torch.float32)

torchaudio.save("changed_myAudio.wav", waveform, 44100, format="wav")
```